# Reporting Services bubble chart does not show all bubbles

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I made a bubble chart in SSRS, but it does not show all bubbles...
The chart looks like this:
[image]

The data is this:
[image]

Bubble number 10 should be shown twice, and it is shown only 1 time. the second time with log date 2nd of April 2019 is not shown. When I do the same chart in excel with the same data it works.

The properties of the chart is like this:

[image]

It seems like a bug... Any help would be great! 
thanks

Comment: Just a guess. But if you look at the bubbles, they don't align with the 27th March, they are all slightly higher. I would guess this is the average of all the dates within the series group. This probably means ALL the values are being averaged including the 2 entries for ID 10. So, try to add the y-axis values to the Series groups and see if that helps.

Comment: yes, thank you very much this solves the issue, all bubbles are now displayed, but it adds many series groups, which I would like to avoid.